# Chrome Dev Tools: Screen Sizes aren't correct?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries, responsive, pixel

So I want to use the Chrome Dev Tools to make my website responsive, so I clicked on the device toolbar. I used the Dimensions of the iPhone SE to make my first media query, so I wrote: `@media (max-width:375px)`
But any styles written in that media query won't take effect. The reason, as it seems, is that the width of the iPhone is about 1000px. I tested this by increasing the max-width until it started to work. **But the chrome dev tools tell me the Dimensions were 375px by 667px**. What am I doing wrong? Now, I of course can't test/make media queries with that interface.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm, it's difficult to say what's happening here  -- do you have the viewport meta tag set in the head? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Comment: Never knew for what it was, now I know thanks!

Comment: Yeah, because most phones have high Dpi, which means their screen dimensions are larger than the viewport dimensions. iPhone SE has screen size 640 x 1136 but viewport is only 320 x 568 -- this is essentially the *Retina display* to help make text super crisp